# Win32 app crashes depending on method used to access string

Tags: c++, winapi

I am experimenting with creating a class-based abstraction over the Win32 API and I have run into some very strange behaviour where depending on how I access the same piece of data, the application will either crash with error code 1407 or work as expected.

Here is a snippet from my Window.cpp file

```cpp
bool Window::show(const GUI::Application *const app)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW windowClass = { 0 };
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = m_WindowProc;
    windowClass.hInstance = app->getInstance();
    
    // Load standard cursor
    if (!(windowClass.hCursor = ::LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    windowClass.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    windowClass.lpszClassName = app->getAppId().c_str();
    
    // Register window class with system
    if (!::RegisterClassExW(&windowClass))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    OutputDebugStringW(L"Registered window class");
    
    // Actually create the window
    m_handle = ::CreateWindowExW(
        0,
        windowClass.lpszClassName,
        m_title.c_str(),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        m_width, m_height,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        app->getInstance(),
        NULL
    );

    if (!m_handle)
    {
        DisplayErrorMessage(GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    
    OutputDebugStringW(L"Created window");

    ::ShowWindow(m_handle, app->getShowCmd());
    
    OutputDebugStringW(L"ShowWindow executed, going into message loop");

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (::GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    
    // Cleanup resources
    ::UnregisterClassW(windowClass.lpszClassName, app->getInstance());
    
    return true;
}
```

If I change `windowClass.lpszClassName` on line 28 to be `app->getAppId().c_str()` then the application crashes with error code 1407.

Why does this happen? They are accessing exactly the same data and there is no modification of the string performed in-between the first call to `app->getAppId().c_str()` on line 15 and the second call on line 28.

Please note: I know there have been questions on other forums related to this topic but none of those answers actually explained why one line worked over the other which is what I am looking for with this question.

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: `windowClass.lpszClassName = app->getAppId().c_str();` is probably a temporary string who's lifetime ends on this line making the stored pointer dangling.

Comment: Please post your implementation of `GUI::Application::getAppId()`.

Comment: The fix may be `auto className = app->getAppId(); windowClass.lpszClassName = className.c_str();`

Answer (score 2):

Following [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowexw), second argument of `CreateWindowExW` is of type `LPCWSTR` which stands for **L**ong **P**ointer to **C**onstant **W**ide **STR**ing. The `long pointer` part clearly states that you have to provide pointer that will be valid during the function call. That is not the case when you pass a `c_str()` from temporary object returned by `getAppID()`.

Comment: "*That is not the case when you pass a `c_str()` from temporary object returned by `getAppID()`*" - only because the pointer is being saved and used **after** its owning string object has gone out of scope and been destroyed.  Keep the string in scope, then this problem will go away